# setwindowplacement doesn't work for maximized window

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a multi monitor setup. When the window is maximized in secondary monitor, I maximize the window to half of the monitor size in OnSysCommand()
by doing the following:

```
MONITORINFO monitorInfo = { sizeof(MONITORINFO) };
GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monitorInfo);
CRect rc = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
rc.left = rc.left / 2;
SetWindowPos(hWnd, rc.left, rc.right, rc.Width(), rc.Height(),0);
```

This works fine.

But,when the process is stopped and when the window is opened after process startup, the window is maximized to full monitor size, though the window placement is saved on process exit.(flags of WindowPlacement is WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED , showCmd is SW_MAXIMIZE)

In OnShowWindow(), SetWindowPlacement() is used.

Comment: may be value of `rc.left` is zero, and after `rc.left = rc.left / 2;` means 0/2 = 0. it will be same, that's way its not working.

Comment: try this it may work `rc.right = rc.right / 2;` Or
you can try `rc.Width()/2` at the place of `rc.Width()` in `setwindowpos` to make it half.

Comment: rc.left is not zero.When i maximize a opened window, it works.  But when i stop the process, and open the window after startup, window is maximized to monitor size. I expect the window to be shown to half the monitor size, as i store the windowplacement during process shutdown and do setwindowplacement in OnShowWindow

Answer (score 0):

Maximized always ignore the size inside the windows placement structure.
This is completely by design.

The windows placement structure holds only the size of the none maximized / normal window. Only the top left corner of the maximized window is saved. And this cords are in screen coordinates to support multiple terminals.

So you get what you want, if you tell the system to restore the window maximized.

If you want to limit the maximization of the window you have to use a different approach. May be WM_GETMINMAXINFO will do it (I am not sure if it is also consulted, when the window is maximized).

Comment: Instead of WM_GETMINMAXINFO, i limited the maximization in OnSysCommand() when nId = SC_MAXIMIZE. My problem is showing the window in maximized state. Should i need to add SetWindowPos in OnShowWindow also.? My Use case: 1. Open a window, maximize it (works) 2. Restart the process 3. Open the window(doen't work, as it was closed in maximized state.)

Comment: OnSysCommand is not called when the System maximizes the Window via ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE)! So you must use another approach!

Comment: Yes, OnSysCommand wont be called in OnShowWindow. I want to display window which has maximize property set already and limit the maximization size.

Comment: I added SetWindowPos in OnShowWindow(), and it works.